# Mysql join row in table to next row by id (not sequential)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently having some issues with this join
I have a table something like this:

```
id   id_solicitud   fecha                   estado      
1          1        2021-09-17 10:34:43     INICIADA
2          2        2021-09-17 10:35:43     INICIADA
3          2        2021-09-17 10:37:43     EN PROCESO
4          2        2021-09-17 10:42:43     ESPERANDO APROBACION
5          3        2021-09-17 12:34:43     INICIADA
6          2        2021-09-19 11:33:11     APROBADA
7          4        2021-09-21 10:34:43     INICIADA
8          4        2021-09-23 10:34:43     EN PROCESO
9          5        2021-09-26 10:34:43     INICIADA
```

I need to join each row to the next row for the same id_solicitud, as to be able to compute the time it took to move that id_solicitud to the next state. Is this possible with just SQL?

**UPDATE**:
i have this for now, but can't seem to just join only to the next id_solicitud (in sequential order):

```
SELECT A.id, 
    A.id_solicitud,
    A.fecha,
    A.estado,
    A.fecha as INICIO,
    B.fecha as FIN
FROM solicitud A CROSS JOIN solicitud B ON A.id_solicitud = B.id_solicitud
WHERE A.fecha < B.fecha
order by A.id_solicitud desc,A.fecha;
```

It should be as performant as possible, this table has a couple of million rows

EDIT REASON: thats not even remotely performant, that solution I have already tried, can't do subqueries on a table with millions of rows, it timesout

Comment: If you can use window functions, you can use `LAG()` to do this.

Comment: @Barmar not able to use window functions

Comment: This will be difficult to do efficiently without window functions.

Comment: @Barmar how would that be with window functions? this needs to be done like a view, so it can be called from another system

Comment: I don't have much expertise with them, so I can't answer that well.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Barmar I'll give it a shot